# Rails and JSON data, only override if has been updated or new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a whatever cronjob that gets JSON data from an external URL and saves to my database. I'm looking for an option to only add or update records that are new or have been changed since the last rake task. At the moment it just creates over the old data.

**Rake Task**

```
namespace :properties do
  desc "Save Properties from API to database"
  task upload: :environment do

    json = JSON.parse('{"Property":[{"id":"1","street":"123 Fake Street","town":"Someplace","postcode":"000000"}]}')

    json['Property'].each do |data|
      property = Property.create 
      property.id = data['id']
      property.street = data['street']
      property.town = data['town']
      property.postcode = data['postcode']
      property.save
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: You can use find_or_create_by - https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: Thanks Sajin. It lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this I did:

```
json['Property'].each do |data|
 property = Property.find_or_create_by(id: data['id'])
 property.id = data['id']
 property.street = data['street']
 property.town = data['town']
 property.postcode = data['postcode']
 property.save
end
```

Thanks to @Sajin.